# Upgrading router code to Alamofire 4.0 and Swift 3

Tags: iphone, swift, swift3, ios9, alamofire

Upgrading Alamofire to Swift 3 syntax I'm wondering what would be the safest way of upgrading a router based on URLRequestConvertible, (code section currently not conforming). I've tried a few things but my feeling is that the URL encoding might change a little bit.

Although Alamofire seem to have changed extensively the errors i can see directly is that ".GET" triggers a compiler error, as does ParameterCoding.URL that is no longer valid.

The code pattern I have (probably at at least 30 different places in my code) is:

```
// MARK: - AlamoFire Router
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible
{
    static let baseURL = Singleton.sharedInstance.apiURL
    static let apiKey: String = Singleton.sharedInstance.apiKey
    static let applicationId: String = Singleton.sharedInstance.applicationId

    case userPoints()

    var method: Alamofire.Method
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .userPoints:

                return .GET
        }
    }


    var path: String
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .userPoints:

                return "/users/points/user/\(Singleton.sharedInstance.user.id)"
        }
    }

    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest
    {
        let URL_val = URL(string: Router.baseURL)!

        let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL_val.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

        // Send API key and Application ID in the header
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("API-Key apiKey=\(Router.apiKey) applicationId=\(Router.applicationId)", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Authorization")

        let encoding = ParameterEncoding.URL

        #if DEBUG
            print(mutableURLRequest)
        #endif

        switch self
        {
            case .userPoints:

                return encoding.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0
        }
    }
}
```

Very hopeful someone with insight in Alamofire and Swift 3 could help me figure out a solution to conform to the changes.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with the setup. .Get needs to be changed to .get for one thing.

`let URL_val = Router.baseURL.asURL()`

`var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL_val.appendingPathComponent(path))`

move the return outside of the switch statement and move it after.

change `var urlRequest` to `func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest`

```
switch self {
case .userPoints:
    urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: nil)
}

return urlRequest
```

they have a full working example in their docs under CRUD & Authorization

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Would you be able to edit the code to include your changes? As for .url , i've actually tried but the compiler gives you a "Type 'Method' (aka OpaquePointer) has no member 'get' "

Comment: change method to `var method: HTTPMethod` anything else you should be able to find easily in the alamofire docs under "Routing Requests" section. If this doesn't fix everything you should be pretty close because I didn't notice anything else with the code you provided that should be an issue.

Comment: Ok. thanks.  How about this line: mutableURLRequest.setValue("API-Key apiKey=\(Router.apiKey) applicationId=\(Router.applicationId)", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Authorization")   is all this happning behind the scenes in the new Alamofire flow?